# GoodData Dataset Writer Maximum Rows?

Tags: bigdata, etl, gooddata

Is there a maximum number of records that can be uploaded using a GoodData dataset writer in a single load? I have looked around and I do not see a documented value for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit specified!
However, expect things to get significantly slower somewhere between 10 and 100 millions of rows, especially if there are data relationships involved such as keys in the table.